# How do I force a custom FrameworkElement to render changed content?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tree of Visuals. The main window has a full-sized Canvas. The Canvas holds the root of some custom Visuals. The first custom Visual (A) can expand and contract based on what the user is viewing, which are in children (Bs, that are DrawingVisuals). As the main window resizes, I want to add children to or remove children from A. The same may happen when the user scrolls any direction in the view. When children (Bs) are added, I want them to be rendered. (The Bs that are removed are no problem because they are no longer visible anyway.)

Take a scenario: The main window is 640x480. I resize to twice that size, which would reveal more Bs, which then are added to A. So far I cannot get the newly added Bs to render, not even when using Invalidate???() methods of the FrameworkElement. I have tried Invalidate???() in the main window and in the A when Bs are added. (I have not with the Bs, figuring they are new.) It seems like Invalidate???() is not the way to go.

I have found a hack that allows the new Bs to render on resize. In the main window I can remove the A from the Canvas and add it back, which forces the tree to be rerendered:

this.contentCanvas.Children.RemoveRange(0, contentCanvas.Children.Count); // remove root
this.contentCanvas.Children.Add(this.CustomVisual_A); // readd root

For obvious reasons this is not desirable, especailly when scrolling. Specifically, the Bs that are being added and removed are managed in that way because they are quite large, and I need to reduce the memory footprint and increase rendering speed as much as possible. That's why I am going to the trouble.

Can someone help me understand what I need to do to get the newly added Bs to render? Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few calls for this...

```
        element.UpdateLayout();
        element.InvalidateArrange();
        element.InvalidateMeasure();
        element.InvalidateVisual();
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had attempted use of all those (indicated by the Invalidate???() above). I also tried UpdateLayout(). The key piece missing is found in my answer below.

Comment: Thank you WPF-it, I need this to update my user control in order to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this. Even though the FrameworkElement is custom, you need to use the standard `AddVisualChild()` and `RemoveVisualChild()` methods to managed your children:

```
this.AddVisualChild(new B());
...
this.RemoveVisualChild(existingB);
```

You still maintain your own collection of Bs, but it seems that unless you use `AddVisualChild()` and `RemoveVisualChild()` the underlying `FrameworkElement` doesn't see the change (actually Panel, the super class of Canvas).

This may also involve the parent in notification in some way; not sure. Ultimately these collection management methods cause the `OnVisualChildrenChanged()` method, defined on Panel, to be invoked, so it should be implemented in the A. At that time I add/remove the child to/from my internal collection, and then invoke on to base:

```
protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject added, DependencyObject removed)
{
     if (added != null)
     {
        this.children.Add((B) added);
     }

     if (removed != null)
     {
        this.children.Remove((B) removed);
     }

     base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(added, removed);
}
```

This causes some internal indication that rendering is necessary.

I figured something like that had to be occurring because removing A from my custom Canvas and re-adding the A forced the render.